# Is it possible to get OS Support deadline for RHEL and Windows OS using API call

Tags: windows, windows-10, redhat, rhel

Is there anyway we can get OS support deadline using API call. We have RHEL and windows OS VMs.

Comment: The OS can't predict the future. For example, Windows service pack support extends for 24 months after the release of the *next* service pack. When will the next service pack be released? If you could predict the future, you would use that power to buy lottery tickets, not report OS support deadlines. There have also been cases where the support deadline was extended; the OS won't know about policy changes that happened after it shipped.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing might change during a products lifecycle and is unlikely to be exposed as an API.

Microsoft provides normal and extended support (you have to pay for the latter). I'm not aware of any Windows API that provides this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can query this website https://endoflife.software/operating-systems
Be weary that this is maintained by a human and if they enter incorrect data or stop maintaining this website you get incorrect results.

Comment: Hi Joni, 

Thanks for your response. Is it possible for us to get these details programmatically?